# Twilio dials two recipients where one acts as caller

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'll try to explain my requirement. I have 3 entities:

- Controller
- Caller-Recipient (Verified Number)
- Recipient

The end goal is to have `Recipient` receive a call from `Caller-Recipient` as caller-id, but `Caller-Recipient` should not be the one that initiates it. The `Controller` will initiate a call between `Caller-Recipient` and `Recipient`. Here's how I intend to do it.

1. The `Controller` will call the Twilio-Number.
2. The TwiML will dial `Caller-Recipient`.
3. Once `Caller-Recipient` receives the call, it'll dial `Recipient` and connect to the same call.
4. The call between `Caller-Recipient` and `Recipient` convenes.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the /Calls Resource, as described below (Make an outbound call to a phone number - code example), initiating the call first to the `Caller-Recipient`. Once they answer, Twilio will reach out to the URL associated to this API call for TwiML which should return a ``` Dial``Number ``` to the `Recipient`. You can set the callerId to a Twilio number or Verified Caller ID.

[Making Calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls)

[TwiML Dial Verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial)

[TwiML Number Noun](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number)

[TwiML for Programmable Voice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml)

Comment: Thanks Alan, sorry for not replying earlier, I got caught up with life. I did a proof-of-concept, and it works. I'm looking into how I can gain more controls of the call through the API, so far I've tested call status callback and recordings callback but haven't yet found out a way to end the call from `Controller` (rest api).

Comment: Thanks for the update. You can end a call in different ways. That is covered here, Update a Call resource to end the call - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-update-a-call-in-progress-with-url&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!